# Android custom keyboard

Tags: android

I've read the article how to implement an input service method from android website.
I want to develop a custom android keyboard with bigger keys. I've followed the SoftKeyboard example, everything is working well but something important is missing: the candidates view does not give me any candidate.
Does anyone can help how to connect the custom candidates view to internal android suggestion list?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What may not be very clear in the documentation is, the onDisplayCompletions callback is really only for application-supplied completions. The android framework does not have any internal dictionary to suggest words based on what you type, that is the job of the input service method; but there is support for application-based completion, and this is what you are looking at right now.

So, the example does it, but you have to use an application that does suggest stuff. Most text boxes will not.

An example of application that does is Facebook. If you install the Facebook application, go to Messages, click on "To" and turn your device sideways. Then type the start of the name of a friend, and you should see the name of your friends pop in the completion list.